# Flex/Actionscript: Unable to add archive file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, path, swc

I have an Flex 4 application that I am developing in Flash Builder 4.  I'm trying to use a library developed by a coworker, which was delivered as an SWC.

I added the library to the Library Path in the project properties.  Component set: MX + Spark, Framework linkage: Merged into code.

When I attempt to instantiate a component from this library, I get the following error:

```
unable to add archive file: [library].swc$locale\en_US\..\..\resources\images\AcceptButton.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

When I unzip [library].swc, the image does exist in .\resources\images\AcceptButton.png as I would expect.

Any suggestions to go about resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The swc isn't corrupt is it? If your coworker re-exports it does it work properly?

Comment: As best I can tell, it's not corrupt.  I can open it with 7Zip and everything looks fine in there, including the images in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to get the uncompressed source code and see if you're having the same problem. It's difficult to guess at what's going wrong inside a swc file. It should function the same way as the SWC.